# How to manage large keystore of client certificates to load test Mutual TLS with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, client-certificates, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to load test a web application that uses mutual TLS. It's a requirement that I use a large data set of client certificates(on the order of 30k). My initial scaled down tests using the keystore configuration as described in [this article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites) worked great but when I configured a keystore with 30k certificates, even with the keystore configuration set to preload=false, JMeter takes around an hour to load the keystore and fails to execute the test, even with a single threadgroup.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to how I could efficiently manage a large keystore?

Answer (score 0):

My initial keystore was a p12, converting it to JKS fixed the issue. Now it loads efficiently and I can run my tests.